# How to fix Contextual closure type '((String, JSON), (String, JSON)) -> Bool' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift4

I am converting my code from swift 3.2 to swift 4 and I am getting error for this code

```
self.arrData = json.sorted{ $0.0.1["chkincount"].doubleValue > $0.1.1["chkincount"].doubleValue }.map { $0.1 }
```

> Contextual closure type '((String, JSON), (String, JSON)) -> Bool' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

How to fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["contextual closure type expects 2 arguments" error when using reduce in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432013/contextual-closure-type-expects-2-arguments-error-when-using-reduce-in-swift-4)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @pkamb I already got answer to my question and the link that you are referring was to there at the I posted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sorted closure changed `$0.0.1` with `$0.1` to access first closure argument and `$0.1.1` with `$1.1` to access second closure argument after making this changes you all set to go.

```
self.arrData = json.sorted{ $0.1["chkincount"].doubleValue > $1.1["chkincount"].doubleValue }.map { $0.1 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this code is working in swift 4 and above is not working ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia I have already write in my answer that you haven't access the second argument `$1` in your closure so you need to access that instead of `$0.1` it is `$1` as of `$0` and `$1` represent `(String, JSON)` not the `((String,JSON),(String,JSON))`

Comment: @VarunNaharia May be they have changed that in Swift 4.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md