# "contextual closure type expects 2 arguments" error when using reduce in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce, swift4, equatable

The following code compiles in Swift 3

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    var removeDuplicate: [Element] {
        return reduce([]){ $0.0.contains($0.1) ? $0.0 : $0.0 + [$0.1] }
    }
}
```

but produces the error

> error: contextual closure type '(_, _) -> _' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

in Swift 4. How to convert this code to be compiled in Swift 4?

Comment: The original error message was due to the spurious `(0)` in the code. But even without that error there remains a Swift 3 to 4 transition problem. I have taken the liberty to edit your question in a way that it is (hopefully) more useful to future readers. – Please check if that is OK for you.

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for all of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Answer (score 15):

The closure passed to `reduce` takes 2 parameters, e.g. `$0` and `$1` in the shorthand notation:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    var removeDuplicate: [Element] {
        return reduce([]) { $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] }
    }
}
```

(This compiles in both Swift 3 and 4.)

In Swift 3 you could use *single* parameter `$0`, which would the be inferred as a tuple with elements `$0.0` and `$0.1`.
This is not possible anymore in Swift 4, as a consequence of [SE-0110 Distinguish between single-tuple and multiple-argument function types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md).

Here is another example demonstrating the change: This

```
let clo1: (Int, Int) -> Int = { (x, y) in x + y }
let clo2: ((Int, Int)) -> Int = { z in z.0 + z.1 }
```

both compiles in Swift 3 and 4, but this

```
let clo3: (Int, Int) -> Int = { z in z.0 + z.1 }
```

compiles only in Swift 3, not in Swift 4.